# Hyperpixel 4 display runs apps vertically in landscape mode

Tags: raspbian, display

I've got a Hyperpixel 4 display which, for some reason, is a vertical first display. I'd like to use it in landscape mode, with the Raspbian terminal-only mode.

Here's what I did: I tweaked the /boot/config.txt to include:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dpi-hyperpixel4 dtparam=rotate=270
```

Now, when the system boots, the terminal displays correctly in landscape. But, there's a hitch. When I launch GUI-based apps, like milkytracker (which uses SDL), they appear as if the screen is vertical. I see the same issue when I start the graphic desktop (startx). Although I can manually rotate the desktop with:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 xrandr --output DPI-1 --rotate right
```

This doesn't seem to work in terminal mode, and any desktop setting adjustments I make don't stick after a reboot. (I also tried to change it through the GUI settings)

How can I set it up so that both my terminal and my apps consistently display in landscape?